# Magento 2.4.6 Sales order view page missing toolbar + layout issue

Tags: magento, layout, backend

I'm using Magento 2.4.6 with Porto theme, a few Amasty modules and Ebizmarts SagePay in dev mode at the moment.

Everything seems to be working as it should except the backend order view page which is missing the top toolbar (where the Send Email / Credit Memo / Hold /Ship / Reorder links should be) and the information that should be in the main content area is shown on the left hand menu area (screenshot below)

[image]

I've tried to go back to no theme or blank theme and that didn't help.
I've looked up the sales_order_view.xml in the files to see if any module was updating it and I've disabled the modules containing a sales_order_view.xml, which didn't help either.
I've checked the exception log and I can't see an error or any error in dev tools in Chrome.

I'm at a loss as to where to look after that, any ideas please?

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to locate the source of the problem through trial and error.
It was due the extension Wyomind Order Eraser and disabling the extension resolved the issue.

I haven't worked out what exactly is the problem with the extension but will update this post if I do.

Answer (score 0):

deploy static theme and see

php bin/magento set:static-content:deploy -f

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately that hasn't made a difference